# How can I configure qmail to automatically BCC a copy of all outgoing email?

Tags: email

I’m running an email server using qmail.

I want to transparently add a BCC to each email that is sent through the server, for particular accounts. This would have the effect of saving every sent email to a separate mailbox for archival and legal purposes.

What’s the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a qmail user, but this is the answer from the qmail FAQ:

> Set QUEUE_EXTRA to `Tlog\0` and QUEUE_EXTRALEN to `5` in extra.h. Recompile qmail. Put > `./msg-log` into `~alias/.qmail-log`
>
> You can also use QUEUE_EXTRA to, e.g., record the Message-ID of every message: run
>
> `| awk '/^$/ { exit } /^[mM][eE][sS][sS][aA][gG][eE]-/ { print }'`
>
> from `~alias/.qmail-log`

More at the bottom of http://cr.yp.to/qmail/faq/admin.html#copies - but I must admit this is completely arcane to me!